# How do i assign s:link to a ui:param value field?

Tags: java, jsf, seam, facelets

I have a template where i need to set a **ui:param**:

```
<ui:param name="pageCononical" value="#{somevalue}"/>
```

The **value="#{somevalue}** needs to be this **s:link**:

```
<s:link id="canonical" view="/rewriteSearchLink/resultsPage.xhtml" propagation="none">
   <f:param name="searchString" value="#{currentSearch.searchString}"/>
   <f:param name="placeString" value="#{currentSearch.placeString}"/>
   <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{currentSearch.currentPage}"/>
</s:link>
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ui:param/>` is intended for passing strings and similarly simple values. The functionality you're after is provided by `<ui:insert/>` and `<ui:define/>`.

In your template you need to indicate an insertion point via `<ui:insert/>`:

```
<ui:insert name="pagecanonical" />
```

In your page, include the template via `<ui:decorate/>` and redefine the `pagecanonical` placeholder with your link:

```
<ui:decorate template="mytemplate.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="pagecanonical">
    <s:link id="canonical" view="/rewriteSearchLink/resultsPage.xhtml" propagation="none">
      <f:param name="searchString" value="#{currentSearch.searchString}"/>
      <f:param name="placeString" value="#{currentSearch.placeString}"/>
      <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{currentSearch.currentPage}"/>
    </s:link>
  </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```